# Cloneable#clone method unnecessary cast

Tags: java, java-8

```
class MyCls implements Cloneable {
  @Override
  protected MyCls clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return new MyCls(//...
  }
}
```

The above code doesn't have any problem. So why does `CopyOnWriteArrayList#clone` returns an `Object` instead of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`? Compiler cries when casting back from `Object` to desired type. What might be the reason for this design decision after all? I see this pattern repeated all over the library.

[Ralph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280244/ralph) suggested that the following code is valid instead of above code:

```
@Override MyCls clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException { 
  MyCls clone = (MyCls)super.clone();
  clone.x = this.x; //or what ever to do return clone
  // ...
}
```

The question still remains the same. Why does `CopyOnWriteArrayList#clone` returns `Object` instead of itself?

Comment: Not the question, but: your cloneable method is wrong! Clone must invoke super.clone but must not call a constructor!  (this is because: if you want to clone a subclass, then the created instance must be the subclass but not `MyCla`)

Comment: @Ralph So does that mean we can get any object as shallow copy of this object? This doesn't make much sense to me. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I recommend to read the Object.clone Javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone) and or Effective Java Chapter "Override clone judiciously" https://books.google.de/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54

Comment: @Override MyCls clone() throws CloneNotSuppoertedException { MyCls clone = (MyCls)super.clone(); clone.x = this.x; //or what ever to do return clone}

Comment: @Ralph That's exactly my point. Why return an `Object` when this can be done: `@Override MyCls clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException { MyCls clone = (MyCls)super.clone(); clone.x = this.x; //or what ever to do return clone}`

Comment: I understand your question, and I wonder too that `CopyOnWriteArrayList.clone` return `Object` but not `CopyOnWriteArrayList` - but I have no clue.

Comment: @Ralph In-fact this pattern is repeated all over the library. There is something that I am unable to recall for a "Aha! Got it" moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is based on [covariant return types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_return_type), i.e. the ability to override a method with a more specific return type.

This feature did not always exist in Java. To be more precise, it was introduced in Java 5, the same version that also introduced the concurrency tools, including `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

But it’s not as if the language update was developed first and the classes afterwards. The classes went through a development process that started before Java 5 and earlier versions  and drafts could be downloaded from http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/

So the earlier versions had to declare the same return type as the overridden method and when they were released together with Java 5, nobody thought in time about changing the method to utilize covariant return types. And apparently still nobody in charge considered it. It might not be important enough.

This is not a unique situation.

The NIO [`Buffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html) API was introduced with JDK 1.4, one version before covariant return types were possible and it took until Java 9, before overrides with more specific return types were added (e.g. [`ByteBuffer.position(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#position(int)), [`limit(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#limit(int)), or [`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#clear()); compare with [the Java 8 version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) having only inherited versions which hindered fluent use of the API).

But mind that changing a method to utilize covariant return types after the class had been published, [can create compatibility problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48693695/2711488) when you compile code under newer JDK versions than it is supposed to run. The solution, [the `--release` option](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/247), also was introduced as late as JDK 9.