# How to fix MCP crash?

Tags: minecraft

I decompiled (`./decompile.sh`) and recompiled (`./recompile.sh`) Minecraft using MCP without any error. But when I start client with `./startclient.sh`, MCP will print [this](https://pastecord.com/igyhofosij.txt).

Note that I didn't modified any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java` and `javac` versions must be 8.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are compiling with jdk9+ and running on jdk8 you need to cast.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/67018142/16341452

(I am unable to install software in my current environment, therefore nothing is tested. Please let me know if anything is wrong)

You can try upgrading your java version or finding the code (in this case net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureUtil.java:293) and replacing it with a cast as described in the above post.