# Keycloak 15.1.0 forgot password

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I've tried in many ways to reset my password from keycloak standalone 15.1.0 but never succesed. Every time it's say "We are sorry...An internal server error has occurred"
I set up already my realm with my email account and gmail host and i Enable Authentication and entered my credentials of the mail account. It's any another settings i need to do?

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkr1q.png)

:56:54,144 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-54) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer; at org.keycloak.vault.DefaultVaultRawSecret.close(DefaultVaultRawSecret.java:90) at org.keycloak.vault.DefaultVaultTranscriber.getStringSecret(DefaultVaultTranscriber.java:96) at org.keycloak.email.DefaultEmailSenderProvider.send(DefaultEmailSenderProvider.java:144) at org.keycloak.email.freemarker.FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.send(FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java:264) at org.keycloak.email.freemarker.FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.sendSmtpTestEmail(FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java:135) at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.RealmAdminResource.testSMTPConnection(RealmAdminResource.java:1013) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor841.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:546) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:435) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:396) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:398) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:110) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215) at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245) at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61) at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41) at org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43) at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39) at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130) at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99) at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387) at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841) at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990) at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486) at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377) at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: read the logs and find any more details (error message, stacktrace) when the error occurs

Comment: I think the issue not related to email configuration. Issue might be caused by varied JDK version. look at to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48694075/5031257

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you should ensure your admin account has its email address set and then use that email address for the `From` field in configuration. You should also enable "less secure apps" in your gmail settings.

@rounakcodes has described the steps in blog post here: https://dev.to/rounakcodes/keycloak-configure-realm-email-settings-gmail-3dfn

Comment: i've the same email for admin and From field. i've used yahoo mail too using :
Yahoo.com (Yahoo! Mail) SMTP Server smtp.mail.yahoo.com
SMTP port 465

And still doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't it print any more details in the log? Can't you enable debug level logs to see what's going on right before the error happens?